# Autoplay next Video after Video 1 is over

Tags: html

I cant write html myself. However if I look at the code I mostly understand what the function is. So we have a autoplay Feature that plays .mp4 Videos when visiting the site as a background. The code below works and the Video loops when its over. But how can I rotate between 3 different videos?

I tried adding the different sources like this (under the original one):

```
<div id="hero-section" class="medium-margin">
    <div class="row hero-unit">
        <div class="hero-overlay"></div>
        <video autoplay loop muted poster="images/poster.jpg" id="bgvid" class="img-fluid">
            <source src="images/Avalo.mp4"type="video/mp4">
            <source src="images/city.mp4"type="video/mp4">
            <source src="images/dragon.mp4"type="video/mp4">
      </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, this will only play and loop the first one.

```
<div id="hero-section" class="medium-margin">
    <div class="row hero-unit">
        <div class="hero-overlay"></div>
        <video autoplay loop muted poster="images/poster.jpg" id="bgvid" class="img-fluid">
            <source src="images/Avalo.mp4"type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess if I cant find an answer I could just make all 3 videos into 1 but doesnt that increase loading times?